Is this equality between supremum and infimums true?

\begin{gather*}
\sup_{(\pi, c, A)}\mathbb E \left[\int_0^\infty \!e^{-\beta t}\,u(c_t) \, \mathrm{d}t - \kappa A_0 - \kappa \int_0^\infty \!e^{-\beta t} \, \mathrm{d}A_t \right] \\
= \sup_{(\pi, c)}\left[\mathbb E \left[\int_0^\infty \! e^{-\beta t} \, u(c_t) \, \mathrm{d}t \right] - \inf_{A}\mathbb E \left[ \kappa A_0 + \kappa \int_0^\infty \! e^{-\beta t} \, \mathrm{d}A_t \right]\right]
\end{gather*}
where $A$ is an increasing continuous process.

I mean, it looks pretty obvious to me, what I wanted to know is if there's some in-between step that I could make explicit. For context, this is an HJB equation coming from an investment-consumption problem with utility $u$ and capital injection process $A$ with cost $\kappa$. Also, $(\pi, c)$ is the amount of money invested-consumption rate that appears in some process that we don't make explicit here because it does not matter.

\begin{align*}\def\d{\mathrm{d}}\def\e{\mathrm{e}}\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}}\def\paren#1{\left(#1\right)}
&\peq \sup_{ \pi, c, A } E\paren{ \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} u(c_t) \,\d t - \kappa A_0 - \kappa \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} \,\d A_t }\\
&= \sup_{ \pi, c } \sup_A E\paren{ \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} u(c_t) \,\d t - \kappa A_0 - \kappa \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} \,\d A_t }\\
&= \sup_{ \pi, c } \sup_A \paren{ E\paren{ \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} u(c_t) \,\d t } - E\paren{ \kappa A_0 + \kappa \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} \,\d A_t } } \tag{1}\\
&= \sup_{ \pi, c } \paren{ E\paren{ \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} u(c_t) \,\d t } + \sup_A \paren{ -E\paren{ \kappa A_0 + \kappa \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} \,\d A_t } } }\\
&= \sup_{ \pi, c } \paren{ E\paren{ \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} u(c_t) \,\d t } - \inf_A E\paren{ \kappa A_0 + \kappa \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} \,\d A_t } }.
\end{align*}
Here (1) requires that $E\paren{ \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} u(c_t) \,\d t }$ and $E\paren{ \kappa A_0 + \kappa \int_0^{+\infty} \e^{-\beta t} \,\d A_t }$ cannot both be $+\infty$ or both be $-\infty$ for any $\pi$, $c$, and $A$.
